# need to repeat function

Tags: jquery

I need your help. I am a noobie and need some help with getting the animation to cycle back to the first function once it finishes.

Here is the code:

```
function phase1()
{
$('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(0).delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(1).delay(2000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(2).delay(3000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(3).delay(4000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(4).delay(5000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase1').delay(6000).fadeTo(500,0, phase2);
};

function phase2()
{
$('#main .home_intro.phase2 h2').delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase2').delay(4000).fadeTo(500,0,phase3);
};

function phase3()
{
$('#main .home_intro.phase3 h2').delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
$('#main .home_intro.phase3').delay(4000).fadeTo(500,0,phase1);
};

phase1();
```

});

Comment: does it currently go through phases 1-3?

Comment: Have you put these functions inside the `$(document).ready` function or outside?

Comment: its inside the $(document).ready function

Comment: please explain what are you trying to do, because for example in phase1 you are showing the h2 tags but hidding the parent...
and when you do the call back you already have hidden the ".phrase1"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it probably is looping back through, but you are fading everything out the first time through, so it disappears, and you aren't seeing any effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have put the functions out side on the `$(document).ready` function then just write this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   phase1(), phase2(), phase3();
});

function phase1() {
    $('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(0).delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(1).delay(2000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(2).delay(3000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(3).delay(4000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase1 h2').eq(4).delay(5000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase1').delay(6000).fadeTo(500,0);
};

function phase2() {
    $('#main .home_intro.phase2 h2').delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase2').delay(4000).fadeTo(500,0);
};

function phase3() {
    $('#main .home_intro.phase3 h2').delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
    $('#main .home_intro.phase3').delay(4000).fadeTo(500,0);
    phase1();
};
```

With the rest of the code on the out side.
And if you need to go from one function to an other put the phase() at the bottom of the function.

Comment: I think he's calling the next function in the last delay of each function: `$('#main .home_intro.phase1').delay(6000).fadeTo(500,0, phase2);`

Comment: that is exactly what I'm trying to do. When I tried the above it displays all three at the same time.